# Django Filter query set

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to add a button which will sort products by name, price etc.

This is my view:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.filter(man=True)
    products = Product.objects.filter(section='man', available=True)
    flt = Product.objects.filter(section='man', available=True).order_by('-name')
    products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,
                  'shop/product/list.html',
                  {'category': category,
                   'categories': categories,
                   'products': products,
                   'flt': flt})
```

How can I sort by name, price etc on click of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing u need to know Sort is different than Filter

this the solution 
in case u add button in html from his action will be redirect to your view named **product_list**

```
<button type="submit" name="sortByName"></button>
```

In your view

After this line 
    products = products.filter(category=category)

Add this

```
if 'sortByName' in request.GET:
    products=products.order_by('-name')
```

and u can reach your goal 
Hope this help u 
Also keep in touch if u have any inquiry
Thanks

Comment: send me your html which include the button action

Comment: yes u make wrong i asked you to add it in form  <form action="addUrURLHere">{%csrf_token%}<button type="submit" name="sortByName">SortBy</button>
</form>

Comment: Ok so please flag the answer  as Right answer